# Can I change OptaPlanner's logging level when using it as a local project dependency?

Tags: logging, log4j2, logback, optaplanner

I have a project in Eclipse which uses OptaPlanner (v8.12.0).  I want to be able to write temporary debug statements within the OptaPlanner code itself, so I:

1. cloned the repo,
2. checked out branch `8.12.x`,
3. built using `mvn`,
4. imported as a pre-existing Maven project `optaplanner-core` (again, Eclipse), and
5. removed the `optaplanner-core` dependency from my Gradle dependencies

Everything compiles and runs just fine, but OptaPlanner no longer responds to my log config changes.

We're using Log4j2 and, when pulling OptaPlanner using the standard build process (Gradle), I can set the log level just fine using the  Log4j2 config.  But, with the src as a project dependency, it's not working.

I have tried:

- Including a local `logback.xml`
- Adding adding as a vm arg: `-Dlogging.level.org.optaplanner=trace`
- Adding adding as a vm arg: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\path\to\log4j2.xml`
- Setting an environment variable `LOGGING_CONFIG=C:\path\to\logback.xml`
- Setting the level programmatically using `Configurator`

Comment: Something here confuses me. You say you use Log4J2. Yet you provide configuration for Logback?

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I thought that OptaPlanner used Logback internally, so I wanted to see if I could get a config picked up.  I double checked and I was mistaken.  Everything goes through SLF4J (as I'm sure you are aware).

Comment: To be clear, my project has a Log4j2 config and I myself have a custom one that I use.  Neither were being picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OptaPlanner only has Logback as a scoped-to-test dependency.

To get a local copy of OptaPlanner to pick up your log config, you need to (locally) add your logging dependency to the OptaPlanner buildpath.

For me, this meant adding a Log4j2 dependency to the OptaPlanner `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>pick.your.favorite</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also deleted the scoped test dependency just to be sure it wouldn't screw with anything.

I suspect, for those not using a dependency management tool, that you could manually add a JAR to the buildpath.

Comment: For more info on how/why to enable/configure logging, see https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#logging